# No puedo compilar esta clase y no logro detectar el error

Tags: java

```
package ex2;

import java.util.Random;

public class ExpSys {
    private Random ran;
    int Level = 1;
    int Exp_Base = 10;
    int Exp = 0;
    int Exp_Max = 0;

    public ExpSys() {
        this.ran = new Random();
        Exp_Max = (Exp_Base * Level) + (ran.nextInt((Level * 0.05)) + (Level * 0.01));
    }

    public void gainExp() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nivel   : " + Level + "Exp necesaria   : " +         Exp_Max + "\nExp actual   : " + Exp);
            int expObt = 1 + ran.nextInt((Level * 2)) + 1;
            Exp += expObt;
            System.out.println("============\nGanaste: " + expObt + "============");
            Level += (Exp <= Exp_Max) ? LevelUp() : 0;
        }
    }

    private int LevelUp() {
        //growStats();
        System.out.println("Subiste al nivel: " + Level + 1);
        Exp_Max = (Exp_Base * Level) + (ran.nextInt((Level * 0.05)) + (Level * 0.01));
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: hasta donde yo se cada clase en Java debe estar precedida de class MiClase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...//aquí la clase
    }
}

Comment: Claro está bien, pero esta es una clase para instanciar, no es el metodo main donde tengo el problema, mira copia mi codigo en una clase que se llame igual o si quieres le das otro nombre corrigiendo el nombre del codigo de igual manera para que no haya conflictos. Luego instancia mi clase en MAIN y llama al metodo gainExp(), luego dime si siquiera puedes compilar el codigo.

Comment: ademas este es Java no JavaScript (solo aclarar)

Comment: el código que puse en el comentario es para Java

Comment: Probaste mi codigo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He copiado tu código y lo he depurado. Parece ser que intentas guardar en una variable INT una operación que te devuelve decimales. Te adjunto una foto con la excepción. Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta de preferencia que el log se texto no imagen es muy difícil de leer